# How to get trace files during "adb am instrument" in Android

Tags: android, adb, android-espresso

we need your help. 
We are collecting trace logs during Android UI tests (espresso) to use for academic research. To obtain trace files, we used "adb am instrument" with "-p" option, referencing this page (https://developer.android.com/studio/command-line/adb#am). The command created a trace file but it includes no logs about the target apps.

We tried the following things:

- Command:
  adb shell 'CLASSPATH=$(pm path androidx.test.services) app_process / androidx.test.services.shellexecutor.ShellMain am instrument -p ./output.log -r -w -e targetInstrumentation com.beemdevelopment.aegis.debug.test/com.beemdevelopment.aegis.AegisTestRunner -e clearPackageData true   -e package com.beemdevelopment.aegis -e debug false androidx.test.orchestrator/androidx.test.orchestrator.AndroidTestOrchestrator'
- Modify the above command:
  -e debug true 
  (the app become no longer work showing white screen)
- Modify the Gradle file:
  testHandleProfiling true (in defaultConfig)
  debuggable true (in buildTypes.debug)